# how to get data from 2nd row

Tags: java, excel

i am trying to get data based on headers in the below first i am geting first row and storing it has keys in map . but the problem is i want to get the data from 2nd row but i got iterator.how can i get data from second row??

```
    DataFormatter df=new DataFormatter();
    Map<String,Integer> m=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/root/Documents/xyz.xlsx"));

        //Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

           Row row=sheet.getRow(0);
           XSSFRow rowe = (XSSFRow)row;
           int s=row.getLastCellNum();
           System.out.println(s);
           for(int i=0;i<s-1;i++){
               String data= df.formatCellValue(rowe.getCell(i));
               System.out.println(data);
                  m.put(data,i);
           }


      Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();       
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow rowa = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

            System.out.println(df.formatCellValue(rowa.getCell(m.get("Member.Member Card Number"))));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
 int count =0;
 while (rows.hasNext()) {

            XSSFRow rowa = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            if(count !=0){
            System.out.println(df.formatCellValue(rowa.getCell(m.get("Member.Member Card Number"))));
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: @leelavinod You are welcome. Mark it answer, if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
while(rowIter.hasNext()){
    XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
    Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
    List list = new ArrayList();
         while(cellIter.hasNext()){
            XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
            list.add(myCell);
          }
     cellVectorHolder.addElement(list);
}
```